# Only screen resolution option is "Default - preferred monitor settings"

Tags: screen, raspi-config

When using the graphics `Raspberry Pi Configuration` tool, or when using `raspi-config` from the command line, the only option for setting the resolution is:

Default-preferred monitor settings.

How do I change this?[image]

Comment: Do you get the same effect if you upgrade to Raspbian Buster from Raspbian Stretch?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when connecting to the Pi while headless using VNC all of the options become available.

If that doesn't work, you can try changing the `hdmi_mode=` part in the `/boot/config.txt` file. Do that according to [this page.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/)

Answer (score 0):

To see all supported video modes you need to enable "OpenGL desktop driver with fake KMS" with `raspi-config` in  `Advanced Options\GL Driver`